# Using external library: No resource identifier found for attribute

Tags: android, xml, resources, external

I am using [BetterSpinner](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1707) in my app.

When I add the xml of the BetterSpinner to my app I get the following issue:

> Namespace 'app' is not bound

I have found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com) and added the following line to my xml layout:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Now there is no parsing issue anymore. 
But when I try to run the app I get a compile error:

```
Error:(32) No resource identifier found for attribute 'met_floatingLabel' in package 'com.example.jublikon'
```

I have added the dependency like that:

```
  compile ('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext', module: 'library'
    }
```

Why does Android Studio not find the resources of a completely included library by gradle?

My complete xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingRight="32dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:id="@+id/title"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="5">

        <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="MaterialBetterSpinner"
            app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="64dp"
        android:paddingRight="64dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="description"
        android:id="@+id/description" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to issue #23 on BetterSpinner Github page:
https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/issues/23

You need to have in your dependencies `MaterialEditText` dependencies.

Did you exclude it like guy in above post?